# Force ARC in static iOS library

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, static-libraries

I am maintaining a static iOS library i inherited from a former coworker using Xcode and Objective-C. The code contains a lot of

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
```

and i was wondering if i can just assume that arc is always available? The library gets distributed to customers so another question would be: Do they maybe have to change something to use my library after i "forced" it to use arc? I already tried to find something about it and so far it seems to me that you can use arc frameworks in non-arc projects. But i'm not completely sure if i got that right and also i don't want any customer to do extra work because of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're distributing it in compiled form, then yes, it either has ARC on or it doesn't, and that's completely under your control. The user of the binary can't change it afterwards; ARC "happens" at compile-time.

If you're distributing it as source, you could document the requirement for ARC, and issue a compilation error if it's lacking by putting a similar guard **in just one place**:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error "MyLibrary requires compilation with ARC"
#endif
```

and remove all the others scattered around.

Finally, code that's compiled with ARC can be freely linked with non-ARC code. The only problem arises if the MRR code does not do proper memory management, but I would classify that as an exposition of an existing bug *in that code* rather than a problem *caused by* using ARC.